# Where is the iOS simulator in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, xcode-simulator

I'm using Xcode 10.1 on Mac 10.13.6.

I'm trying to follow the instructions here -- https://www.macinstruct.com/node/494, for accessing the iOS simulator on my Mac.  After right clicking on Contents -> Applications, all I see is

[image]

Is there something else I need to do to get the iOS simulator installed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The iOS simulator is installed with Xcode. Unfortunately the instructions you're following are now outdated.

In order to start the simulator, you simply start Xcode and then in the top menu select `Xcode` > `Open Developer Tool` > `Simulator`.